# Module feature not shown in iis7 manager

Tags: iis-7

When I open the iis7 manager (on vista ultimate) i see a lot of feature icons displayed like .NET compilation, ISAPI filters. But I do not see the Module icon. Where is it determined what I see in iis7 manager and how can I get de Module feature to be shown?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1160672/1916059.aspx) is a pretty good forum topic over on IIS.Net that goes through a similar scenario.

Basically, the best recommendation is to reinstall IIS. This is due to the fact that even after you fix/implement a workaround, you will most likely have some other problems with your installation.